# Redirecting to a Blazor page after running an animation

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a component and the html portion looks like this. This is an
animation that runs for about 50 seconds

```
        <div class="contents">
            <img src="images/animated.png" class="contents"/>
        </div>
```

The code behind looks like this.

```
            public partial  class AnimatedLoader
            {
                [Inject] public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

                [Parameter] public int Time { get; set; } = 5;


                protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
                {
                    if (firstRender)
                    {
                        await StartTimerAsync();
                        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("testpage");
                    }
                }

                public async Task StartTimerAsync()
                {
                    while (Time > 0)
                    {
                        Time--;
                        StateHasChanged();
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
```

When the animation runs and completes  I want to be able to redirect to a page called testpage

Here is html code for testpage

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 offset-2 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
                    @if (projectModel != null){
                        <EditForm EditContext="@EditContext">
                            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                            <div class="mb-5">
                                <label for="projectnameinput" class="form-label">Name your project*</label>
                                <InputTextOnInput type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg cust" Validate="@pNameValidation" id="projectnameinput" @bind-Value="@projectModel.ProjectName" @onkeyup="KeyboardEventHandler" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-5">
                                <label for="projectnumberinput" class="form-label">Enter your project number*</label>
                                <InputTextOnInput type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg cust" Validate="@pNumValidation" id="projectnumberinput" @bind-Value="@projectModel.ProjectNumber" @onkeyup="KeyboardEventHandler" />
                            </div>
                        </EditForm>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the code behind for testpage

```
            private NewProjectVM projectModel = new();
            private EditContext EditContext;
            
            protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
         
                        EditContext = new EditContext(projectModel);
                        EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;

                    });
                }

                protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
                {
         
                }
```

The animation component was placed on a page to run. The animation runs very well without any problem
but the redirect to the testpage does not work and instead I get the error message below.

```
        [2021-09-13T23:04:52.222Z] Error: System.InvalidOperationException: EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these.
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.OnParametersSet()
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
```

You cannot use EditContext and Model together. What is wrong here? Why is the redirection to testpage not working?

Answer (score 0):

I've had serious problems with Timers created in Blazor page events.  I'd strongly recommend not doing this.  In almost this exact same scenario, I found that my created Timer only ticked on 95% of page loads.  Never found out why.

For me, it was critical-- I was doing a page animation, and then revealing buttons to log in or take a tour.  When customers don't GET those buttons, I instantly lose a customer.